Confusion over $|\det(A)|\leq{\|A\|^n}$
I was having a bit of trouble understanding the exact context of an exercise in my analysis textbook, Basic Analysis 2 by Jiri Lebl.
Exercise: Given an n-by-n matrix $A$, prove that $|\det(A)|\leq{\|A\|^n}$. (This is exactly how it is stated)
The thing I am mainly confused about is what normed vector space the problem applies to. I understand that $\det:L(X)\to{\mathbb{R}}$ is a well defined function independent of basis or norm, but the operator norm depends on what norm the vector space is equipped with. In this context are we talking about any finite dimensional normed vector space or specifically $\mathbb{R^n}$ with the standard euclidean norm.
I found out how to prove the statement for the latter, that is if we are talking about $(\mathbb{R^n},\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{R^n}})$. First proving that if $\|A\|=1$, then $\|Ax\|_{\mathbb{R^n}}\leq{\|x\|_{\mathbb{R^n}}}$, which means $$a_j=\|Ae_j\|_{\mathbb{R^n}}\leq{\|e_j\|_{\mathbb{R^n}}}=1$$ where $a_j$, $j=1,...,n$ are the column vectors of $A$. It then follows using Hadamard's inequality that $\det(A)\leq{1}$. The general result for arbitrary $A$ follows by normalizing and applying linearity, $$\det([\frac{a_1}{\|A\|}\dots\frac{a_n}{\|A\|}])\leq{\|\frac{A}{\|A\|}\|^n}=1$$$$\implies\frac{\det(A)}{\|A\|^n}\leq{\frac{\|A\|^n}{\|A\|^n}}\implies\det(A)\leq{\|A\|^n}.$$
Thanks in advance.

It seems that linearity (for which function, ?) cannot be applied here so easily because $det$ isn't linear it means that $det(A+B)\neq det(A) +det(B)$ in general.

@Anthony Corsi $Ae_j$ are the coulumn vectors of $A$, $a_j$ is its Euclidean norm.

@EDX OP is applying the well-known property $\det(\lambda A) = \lambda^n \det(A)$.

This holds not just for all operator norms, but for all matrix norms. We can use an argument similar to the one found here to show that $|A| \le 1 \implies \det(A) \le 1$.

@azif00 Yes i was talking about the inequality that may hold for continous (in a finite dimension linear space) application.

@Theo Bendit, so when you say $|A|\leq{1}\implies\det(A)\leq{1}$ holds for all operator norms, do you mean the inequality holds regardless of the specified norm on the vector space?

@AnthonyCorsi Yes, that is what I mean.

It is not clear what norm is being used, but it is well known that spectral radius is a lower bound of all sub-multiplicative matrix norms. (A matrix norm is called sub-multiplicative if $\|XY\|\le\|X\|\|Y\|$ for all matrices $X$ and $Y$. In particular, all operator norms are sub-multiplicative, but there are other sub-multiplicative norms that are not operator norms, such as Frobenius norm.)
So, if the norm in question is sub-multiplicative, then $|\det(A)|=\prod_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i(A)|\le\rho(A)^n\le\|A\|^n$.
